# No value specified when query is too big

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have type in my elasticsearch index with keyword type called "category_urls" which contains a list of urls for particular item.

Then I'm trying to count all items which have provided category urls.

```py
 urls = [*lots of urls here*]
 query = {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "category_urls": urls
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "in_stock": True
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
 count = elastic_search.count(index=settings.ELASTIC_PRODUCTS_INDEX, body=query)['count']
```

However whenever I try to supply query with enough big list, it throws

```
{RequestError}RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'No value specified for terms query')
```

It is definitely connected to the size, since if I test this on small lists it works perfectly but, for example, on 280 urls it starts saying no value specified.
Is there someworkaround or fix for this issue?
My elasticsearch version is 6.8.10.

Comment: Can you provide your actual query in JSON format? I am pretty sure its some formatting issue with big list

Comment: @Supremus Elasticsearch by default limits the terms query to a maximum of 65,536 terms, so this cannot be a size issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for comment hinting that this is not size issue. It actually wasn't. One of urls was None, so this caused this error. Although i would prefer if message was more clear.